# How to test a class with token using IConfiguration

Tags: .net, mocking, xunit

I use Xunit in the .Net framework. This class is GenerateJWT that has a parameter is User type (Object) which needs to be tested, I want to mock the IConfiguration Interface but don't know exactly if it is correct or not. The goal is to input a string expect that needs to match to string result

```
public string GenerateJWT(User userInfo)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.Phone),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

            var encodeToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return encodeToken;
        }
```

This class below is my test, I use Mock class to Mock IConfiguration interface that returns a code

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task GenerateJWT_Return_Token()
        {  
            //Arrange
            var mock_service = new Mock<IUserAdminService>();
            var mock_config = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            User login = new User() { Id = 2, FullName = "abc", AddressDetail = "A", CityId = "123", DistrictId = "123", WardsId = "123", Password = "03RCzu/LT/48EeliJG9L/ZS/ITwGAYUUoALJSePkG5k=", Gender = "male", Phone = "0123456789", DOB = "5/5/1999", Avatar = "" };

            var x = "03RCzu/LT/48EeliJG9L/ZS/ITwGAYUUoALJSePkG5k=";
            mock_config.Setup(m => m["Jwt:Key"]).Returns(x);
          
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, login.Phone),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };
            var token= new JwtSecurityToken(
                x,
                x,
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);
            //Act
            var service = new LoginAdminService(mock_config.Object, mock_service.Object);

            string result = service.GenerateJWT(login);
            var encodeToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
           
            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(encodeToken, result);
        }
```

The test got message failure, I don't know how to deal with that. I need some advice from you guys
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is probably that the *GenerateJWT* method is using *DateTime.Now*.
This is someting that you have no direct control over and will change anytime the test is run. In your test you're also creating a token by calling *DateTime.Now*, but there probably still is a sleight milisecond differnce between the token to check and the generated token.

If you want to be able to test this method you will need to use a wrapper class for providing the current time.
This could look something like this:

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
   DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

You would then need to change the *GenerateJWT* method to also accept a DateTimeProvider instance from outside:

```
public string GenerateJWT(User userInfo, IDateTimeProvider dateProvider) 
{
  ...
  var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
      issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
      audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
      claims,
      expires: dateProvider.Now.AddMinutes(120),
      signingCredentials: credentials);
  ...
}
```

This way you can completely control everything from your test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GenerateJWT_Return_Token()
{
  //Arrange
        var mock_service = new Mock<IUserAdminService>();
        var mock_config = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        var mockProvider = new Mock<IDateTimeProvider>();
        User login = new User() { Id = 2, FullName = "abc", AddressDetail = "A", CityId = "123", DistrictId = "123", WardsId = "123", Password = "03RCzu/LT/48EeliJG9L/ZS/ITwGAYUUoALJSePkG5k=", Gender = "male", Phone = "0123456789", DOB = "5/5/1999", Avatar = "" };

        var x = "03RCzu/LT/48EeliJG9L/ZS/ITwGAYUUoALJSePkG5k=";
        mock_config.Setup(m => m["Jwt:Key"]).Returns(x);

        mockProvider.Setup(m => m.Now).Returns(new DateTime(2022, 4, 22, 16, 0, 0));
      
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, login.Phone),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };
        var token= new JwtSecurityToken(
            x,
            x,
            claims,
            expires: mockProvider.Object.Now.AddMinutes(120),
            signingCredentials: credentials);
        //Act
        var service = new LoginAdminService(mock_config.Object, mock_service.Object);

        string result = service.GenerateJWT(login, mockProvider.Object);
        var encodeToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
       
        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(encodeToken, result);
}
```